# Windows phone xap testing and sharing

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developping an application with Cordova targeted for Windows phone 8.

I'm able to build a De bug or Release Xap for windows phone and deploy it on device using usual tools. The matter is that my clients want to test it too but they don't have any of sdk tools (only a device).

What is the better solution to do that ?

Installing Xap file from sd card or phone storage doesn't work (company issue message). Sign xap with sdk tools for testing and then retry to install it from sdcard doesn't work.

Is the beta test store the only solution ? (Very long procedure)

Ty fort any tips...

Comment: beta test store the easiest solution. For that you need to have a developer account and need to update your app as a beta app with the live id provided for beta testers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just to create a beta and send them a download link. It's done in less then 5 minutes and you can update the app quickly, publish it again and retest it within minutes.